# Formatt Number Java Error

Tags: java, numberformat

Tengo unos valores , y tengo un formatter que lo que hace es dejar los numeros con los puntos en los miles y comas para decimales, pero si llega 0 0 0,00 me printa en el resultado lo siguiente :  ,00 
Alguna idea dejo el formatter que utilizo y la expresion donde lo utilizo, simplemente le llega un doble y hace el format.

```
DecimalFormat formatterWithDecims = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");   
formatterWithDecims.format(obj.getValor));
```

Comment: *me printa en el resultado lo siguiente :  ,00* ¿? ¿Has leído la documentación? Es exactamente el resultado que debería mostrarte. ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes/cuál es el problema?

Comment: Pues que en el caso de venir cualquier numero ...me ahce el format correcto (puntos en los miles , comas para decimales y me muestra 2) , pero en caso de que me viene el 0 me muestra  ,00 y a mi me gustaria 0,00

Comment: Quizá mas o menos con `String F=obj.getValor==0?"0,00":"#,###.00";` y luego instancias el `DecimalFormat` a partir de ese `String`. no?